# How to Add / Remove fieldsets with Jquery - better example

Tags: jquery

We wish to allow our users to add/remove fieldsets according to their needs.

Here's the code I've come up with:

The jquery part:

```
$("#inputRow1").hide();
$("#inputRow2").hide();
$("#remove-last").hide();

$("#add-more").click(function(){

    //count how many *direct children* elements are hidden.
    var hiddenElements = $('#members >:hidden').length;

    $("#remove-last").show();    

    if (hiddenElements === 2) {
        $("#inputRow1").show();
    } else if(hiddenElements === 1) {
        $("#inputRow2").show();
        $(this).hide();
    }
});

$("#remove-last").click(function(){

    //count how many *direct children* elements are hidden.
    var hiddenElements = $('#members >:hidden').length;
    $("#add-more").show();    

    if (hiddenElements === 0) {
        $("#inputRow"+2).hide();
    } else if (hiddenElements === 1) {
         $("#inputRow"+hiddenElements).hide();
        $(this).hide();
    }

});
```

The HTML part (server side generated):

```
<div id="members">
    <div id="inputRow0">
        <input id="input0_0" class="input" type="text" /><br/>
        <input id="input0_1" class="input" type="text" /><br/>
        <input id="input0_2" class="input" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div id="inputRow1">
        <input id="input1_0" class="input" type="text" /><br/>
        <input id="input1_1" class="input" type="text" /><br/>
        <input id="input1_2" class="input" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div id="inputRow2">
        <input id="input2_0" class="input" type="text" /><br/>
        <input id="input2_1" class="input" type="text" /><br/>
        <input id="input2_2" class="input" type="text" />
    </div>
</div>  
<br /><a id="add-more" href="#">add-more</a> <a id="remove-last" href="#">remove-last</>
```

Link:
http://jsfiddle.net/URkuW/

I'm aware that his code while it works, it's very naif.

Isn't there a *better* / *shorter* / *more compreehsive* / *more re-usable* / way of doing it ? :D

Comment: You should post this on Code Review if it already works..

Comment: what is Code Review ?

Comment: Do you want to add new fields as in your current code you are just show hide existing html elements.

Comment: @rahularyansharma - True I'm not using Append and Remove methods. I'm only showing and hidden them. I do have an issue with this, because, for some odd reason, the javascript required validation on this fields, even the hidden ones, is triggered. Even if I disabled="disabled" they seem to get triggered. So, I may perhaps need to use append and remove, BUT, if I do that, the user may loose previous added inputs if they happen to have a need for retrieve them back... So. I'm clueless.

Comment: You can manage validation using jquery on dynamically created elements and as far retain values of removed elements have no sense . As user wants to remove those elements, Its means He/She don't want those inputs, then what can be objective behind retaining values of removed elements .

Comment: Well, the only reason I wish to remove the elements from the DOM was to really make sure the validation discard those elements that are "hidden". Otherwise, we do still get those "field are required messages". But like you, I see that we have a major drawback there. Hence, I still clueless about how to deal the the big issue. This question, however, is related with a smaller issue, only regarding the short version of this code. :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rahularyansharma/b5LC8/1/

Comment: @rahularyansharma care to explain this line: eq(-1).remove(); ?

Comment: This will remove last element from that div of input type .http://api.jquery.com/eq/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my go at it : http://jsfiddle.net/URkuW/7/

I added a class `inputRow` to your "rows"

```
function updateVisibility(){
    var cnt = $('#members .inputRow:visible').length;
    $('#add-more').toggle(cnt < 3);
    $('#remove-last').toggle(cnt > 1);
}

$("#inputRow1").hide();
$("#inputRow2").hide();
updateVisibility();

$("#add-more").click(function(){
    $('#members .inputRow:hidden').first().show();
    updateVisibility();
});

$("#remove-last").click(function(){
    $('#members .inputRow:visible').last().hide();
    updateVisibility();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your *JQuery code* like below, Try that,

**Fiddle Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/URkuW/5/

**CSS :**

```
.divShow
{
    display: block;
}
.divHide
{
    display: none;
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<div id="members">
    <div id="inputRow0" class="divShow">
        <input id="input0_0" class="input" type="text" /><br/>
        <input id="input0_1" class="input" type="text" /><br/>
        <input id="input0_2" class="input" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div id="inputRow1" class="divHide">
        <input id="input1_0" class="input" type="text" /><br/>
        <input id="input1_1" class="input" type="text" /><br/>
        <input id="input1_2" class="input" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div id="inputRow2" class="divHide">
        <input id="input2_0" class="input" type="text" /><br/>
        <input id="input2_1" class="input" type="text" /><br/>
        <input id="input2_2" class="input" type="text" />
    </div>
</div>  
<br /><a id="add-more" href="#">add-more</a> <a id="remove-last" href="#" class="divHide">remove-last</>
```

**JQuery :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var tot = $('div[id^="inputRow"]').length;
$("#add-more").click(function() {        
    $('div[id^="inputRow"]:hidden:first').show();    
    ShowHide();
});
$("#remove-last").click(function() {
    $('div[id^="inputRow"]:visible:last').hide();
    ShowHide();;
});
function ShowHide()
{
    var vislen = $('div[id^="inputRow"]:visible').length;
    if(vislen>1)
        $("#remove-last").show();
    else
        $("#remove-last").hide();
    if(vislen == tot)
        $("#add-more").hide();
    else
        $("#add-more").show();
}
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Nice effort I believe. However, It's starts with 0 instead of 1, the add button and remove button don't disappear when they should, and most importantly, we can only make "add" and "remove" once. If after you insert and remove all fields, you try to repeat the process, it will not work.

Comment: @MEM : I have updated my code, It seems to be ok now... Try the same

Comment: Again, thanks. But two issues still remain. 1) inputRow0 should appear at the beginning. 2) the "remove-last" should NOT appear at first. And "add-more" should not appear at last. (I've tried to worked out on your code. But I lack the skills).